# How to sync the PlayerPrefs from my unity game for iOS to iCloud

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, icloud

After downloading some assets to help me sync my `PlayerPrefs` of my game made in unity for iOS to iCloud so users could retrieve their data on other devices I realized that most of them were outdated or simply did not work.
At this point I have kind of hit a dead end and am wondering if any of you either know of plugins that could help me sync my PlayerPrefs or tutorials or other sources that could help me learn to do so myself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not familiar with databases like me this service is the easiest way to do it = http://dreamlo.com

Also please check it
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KZuqEyxYZCc

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, however i am fairly familiar with storing data using databases and in this instance I want to use iCloud and not any other alternate method EDIT: funnily enough, I have actually already used dreamlo for online highscores and agree with you that it is very good